Can't update records code.org app lab sign in page
I am trying to create a sign in page for an app in code.org, and I keep getting the error:
WARNING: Line: 36: updateRecord() record.id parameter value (undefined) is not a number.
ERROR: Line: 36: missing required parameter "tableName"
I have tried messing around with the code and names of parameters. Please help, here is the code:
onEvent("originalsignup", "click", function( ) {
  createRecord(getText("originalusernameinput"), {Username:(getText("originalusernameinput")) , Photo:(getImageURL("originalprofilephotoinput")) , Email:getText("originalemail") , Name:(getText("nameinput")) , Password:getText("originalpasswordinput"), }, function(record) {
    
  });
  setScreen("signinscreen");
});
onEvent("signupbutton", "click", function( ) {
  setScreen("signupscreen");
});
onEvent("signinbutton", "click", function( ) {
  readRecords(getText("usernameinput"), {}, function(records) {
    for (var i =0; i < records.length; i++) {
      if(records[i].Password == getText("passwordinput") ) {
        setScreen("profilescreen");
      }else
      {
        console.log("Incorrect Password or Username");
        setProperty("passwordinput", "text", "");
      }
      setImageURL("image2", records[i].Photo);
      setProperty("profilename", "text", records[i].Name);
      setProperty("profilescreenemail", "text", records[i].Email);
      setProperty("profileusername", "text", records[i].Username);
    }
  });
});
onEvent("profilepictureselect", "input", function( ) {
  setProperty("image2", "image", getImageURL("profilepictureselect"));
});
onEvent("logoutbuttonprofile", "click", function(logout ) {
  setScreen("signinscreen");
  setProperty("passwordinput", "text", "");
  setProperty("usernameinput", "text", "");
});
onEvent("updateinfobuttonprofile", "click", function(updateinfo) {
  updateRecord(getProperty("originalusernameinput", "text"), {Username:(getText("profileusername")), Email:(getText("profilescreenemail")), Name: (getText("profilename")), Photo: (getImageURL("profilepictureselect"))}, function() {
    setScreen("infoupdatescreen");
    setProperty("displaynewinfousername", "text", getText("profileusername"));
    setProperty("displaynewinfoname", "text", getText("profilename"));
    setProperty("displaynewinfoemail", "text", getText("profilescreenemail"));
    setProperty("displaynewinfoprofilephoto", "image", getImageURL("profilepictureselect"));
  });
});

I AM PUTTING THIS HERE BECAUSE THE POST MADE ME
